# Can header scroll with content in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have looked through all the documentation and github issues and I can't find anything that answers this question. I want the set react-navigation header (which I set to a component with `headerTitle: <Header />` to scroll with the page, I don't want it to be static at the top of the page. Is this possible in react-navigation for react native?

I have tried making the `header=null` and then manually adding the header to each page in my stack, but then the header re-renders with every new page in the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, React-navigation works with static headers. The actual view for the app in this case starts after the header and continues until a tab navigator if you have one.

If you want that scroll header in just a screen or two, it will be better to do it yourself actually. It will be easier and will take less time. However if you want it for the whole app I think it would be better to reconsider that and try to modify the native_modules react navigation package which I do not recommend

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. I just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something, so apparently, I wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can set `headerMode: screen` in your stack. I hope this helps you.

Comment: After setting the `headerMode: screen` in your stack. You can give the any headerTitle you want inside each screen by   `static navigationOptions = { };`

Comment: Or another way of doing this is set `header: null` in your stack and remove default reactnavigation headers and create your own reusable header component with props, which is a relief. I can give you tips in making custom header component if you go for this solution.